# How fix crash when react native picker dataset change

Tags: react-native

I`m using picker from react-native library. When selects item from picker and update the data set of the picker with array that has length less than previously selected item's index causes to crash the app.

```
<Picker
  style={{flex: 1}}
  selectedValue={selectedTime}
  onValueChange={(value) => {
  this.setState({
     selectedTime: value,
  });
 }}>

   {array && array.map((element, index) => {
      return (
          <Picker.Item
              label={element}
              value={element}
              key={index}
          />
      );
   })}
</Picker>
```

I checked this error using android studio and it show that is a `IndexOutOfBound` error

Comment: when u delete this code lines project was work ?

Comment: @errorau yes, It works without these lines

Comment: Could you please share u construction with state?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, ever found the solution?

Comment: @SantiagoGil Not yet

Comment: try:npm uninstall react-native-picker , then:
npm install --save @react-native-community/picker